# Droid Explorer issue

Tags: droid-explorer

Unable to locate the Android SDK tool, Please reinstall the application.
I have done  SDK download and the exact path I have put. But the same error occurs again and again.
I uploaded the video in Dropbox, please watch.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7xgbrigv1i01sp/Untitled%202.mp4?dl=0

Thanks.

Comment: The validaton code is here:
https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/blob/1909e142be47d1bc084c4dd79d7b7feb4c0bcc45/DroidExplorer.WixCA/AndroidSdkCustomActions.cs
`build-tools`, 'tools' and 'pltoform-tools' must be present... (there might be more checks..)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the SDK tools from the site, you need to run `sdkmanager tools platform-tools  "build-tools;28.0.3" platforms;android-28`. (You might want to check the relevant `build-tools` and `platform` versions with `sdkmanager --list`).

That gets it to install... To actually be useful, you [might need to downgrade some tools](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/63).